# Passing dynamic arrays to recieve inputs in separate functions

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I would like to pass dynamic arrays to functions and receive user input. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 struct make
 {
     int part;
     int graph;
     int like;
 };

 int z;
 int *p = new int [z]; 

 void inpart( make x[],int *fig)
 {
     cout << "Input part\n";
     cin >> x[*fig].part;
 }

 void ingraph(make x[],int *tig)
 {
     cout << "Input graph\n";
     cin >> x[*tig].graph;
 }

 void inlike(make x[],int *gig)
 {
     cout << "Input like\n";
     cin >> x[*gig].like;
 }

 int main()
 {
     cout << "Input array count\n";
     cin >> z;

     make p[z];   
     for (int i=0; i < z; i++)
     {
         inpart(p,&z);
         ingraph(p,&z);
         inlike(p,&z);
     }
     for (int i=0; i < z; i++)
     {
         cout << "the result is\n";
         cout << p[z].part << ", ";
         cout << p[z].graph << ", ";
         cout << p[z].like << "\n";
     }
 }
```

My input 1,1,1 for all the structure objects should output 1,1,1. However, the answer I receive is 1,0,2. Why?

Comment: Use `std::vector<>` with a reference and forget everything else.

Comment: The shown code in this question lacks any kind of logical indentation, and that makes it mostly unreadable. If you would like to ask others for help, the least you could do is spend a little bit of time formatting your code with logical indentation, so that other people can actually read it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, pardon me. I'll be taking care of the indentation in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't trying to initialize a static buildin array in run-time:
Your implementation is wrong here:

```
cout<< "Input array count\n";
cin>>z;//initialized in run-time
make p[z]; // wrong, need to be allocated with new
make* example = new make[z]; // Ok!
```

Secondly, you're trying to read and write out of bounds of the created array. It's Undefined behaviour. When you're creating an array with size N, chunk of the memory will be allocated to which you can have access by index. In your case from 0 to z or [0,z), excluding z. To sum up, your cycle should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
  inpart(p,&i);
  ingraph(p,&i);
  inlike(p,&i);
}
```

Actually u've made a lot of mistakes in your code, but I feel like you will understand this later when continue learning.